# helm filebeat pod crashing on AKS (Azure k8s) with CrashLoopBackOff caused by : Exiting: cannot obtain lockfile

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, filebeat

I am trying to setup a elk cluster with this helm repo : `elastic https://helm.elastic.co`. Elastic-Search has been succesfully setup with `helm install elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch --namespace=logging`. While trying to setup filebeat with `helm install filebeat elastic/filebeat --namespace=logging --values filebeat-values.yaml` where `filebeat-values.yaml`is :

```
daemonset:
  extraEnvs:
    - name: "ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME"
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: elasticsearch-master-credentials
          key: username
    - name: "ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD"
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: elasticsearch-master-credentials
          key: password

filebeatConfig:
  filebeat.yml: |
    logging.metrics.enabled: false
    filebeat.inputs:
      - type: container
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/agri-check*.log
        json:
          keys_under_root: true
          overwrite_keys: true
        processors:
          - add_kubernetes_metadata:
              host: ${NODE_NAME}
              matchers:
                - logs_path:
                    logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
      - type: container
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/*.log
        exclude_files: ['.*/agri-check.*$']
        processors:
          - add_kubernetes_metadata:
              host: ${NODE_NAME}
              matchers:
                - logs_path:
                    logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"

    output.elasticsearch:
      host: '${NODE_NAME}'
      hosts: "https://elasticsearch-master:9200"
      username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}'
      password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}'
      protocol: https
      ssl.verification_mode: none
```

One of the filebeat pods (one for each node in the k8s nodepool) is crashing with : `filebeat-filebeat-x74hz     0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (3m7s ago)    9m2s` caused by

```
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-07-13T08:55:56.776Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":392},"message":"filebeat stopped.","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-07-13T08:55:56.776Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1057},"message":"Exiting: cannot obtain lockfile: connot start, data directory belongs to process with pid 8","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
Exiting: cannot obtain lockfile: connot start, data directory belongs to process with pid 8
```

This is the only pod that crashes. The other pods on the other nodes are running fine and I have the same setup on a different cluster (the QA-Cluster). It is a bit of a problem as the setup only continues when one pod per K8s-Node is started. The connection to elastic-search is running properly. A research on the internet is telling me to delete the lockfile (`https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-crashloopbackoff/320830`). But I can't as the pod ist stopped and i cannot connect to it per Shell. Do I have some other debugging possibilities ?